# How to add a className to all child routes?

Tags: react-router

I have a Route that has a component with this in its render() :

```
<div>
  <Nav/>
      {this.props.children}
  <Footer/>
</div>
```

How do I give all components that are rendered through it as children a className?

I've tried this:

```
<div>
  <Nav/>
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div />, { className: 'test' })}
  <Footer/>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm assuming the className went on the Route component instead of the component that was passed to the Route component?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: The answer I got on the forum was it can't be done, your components have to explicitly accept the className prop

Comment: thread on forum - https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/react-cloneelement-ignores-classname-in-passed-in-props/2875/3

Comment: Thanks for the reply